# Updating GridView not being called

Tags: asp.net

I am working with a GridView (programmaticaly)but I am having trouble with the updating method. I click int the Edit link button, then I make the changes I want but, when I click the Update link button, it returns to the edit method, not calling the updating method.

Any idea why?

Here is the code:

```
   datagrid.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;

        datagrid.RowUpdating += new GridViewUpdateEventHandler(datagrid_RowUpdating);
        datagrid.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(datagrid_RowEditing);

    protected void datagrid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        datagrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        datagrid.DataBind();
    }

    private void datagrid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Well, you are not telling it to do anything in your `datagrid_RowUpdating` method...

Comment: Maybe the Update argument does not have any new values? Try adding them `e.NewValues.Add(key, value)`

Answer (score 0):

There is no code into your `RowUpdating` event of `GridView`.Try to find `RowIndex` inside your `RowUpdating` event like

```
// get the information 
   int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
   GridViewRow row = datagrid.Rows[rowIndex];
//Find the controls by using `FindControl` method.
```

Link for your help [edit-delete-update](http://hightechnology.in/gridview-edit-delete-update/)

Hope you understand and works for you.